# std::ofstream with std::ate not opening at end

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

I am trying to open a file for output and append to it. After appending to it, I want to move my output position somewhere else in the file and *overwrite* existing data. As I understand it, `std::ios_base::app` will ***force*** all writes to be at the end of the file which is *not* what I want to do. As such, I believe `std::ios_base::ate` is the correct flag to pass to `std::ofstream::open()`. However, it seems to be not working as expected:

```
// g++ test.cpp
// clang++ test.cpp
// with and without -std=c++11
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::streampos fin, at;
    {
        std::ofstream initial;
        initial.open("test", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        if ( not initial.good() ) {
            std::cerr << "initial bad open" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        int b = 100;
        initial.write((char*)&b, sizeof(b));
        initial.flush();
        if ( not initial.good() ) {
            std::cerr << "initial write bad" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        fin = initial.tellp();
    }
    {
        std::ofstream check;
        check.open("test", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::ate);
        if ( not check.good() ) {
            std::cerr << "check bad open" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        at = check.tellp();
        if ( fin != at ) {
            std::cerr << "opened at wrong position!\nfin:\t" << fin << "\n" << "at:\t" << at << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        int bb = 200;
        check.write((char*)&bb, sizeof(bb));
        check.flush();
        if ( not check.good() ) {
            std::cerr << "check write bad" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        at = check.tellp();
    }
    if ( (fin + std::streampos(sizeof(int))) != at ) {
        std::cerr << "overwrite?\nfin:\t" << fin << "\n" << "at:\t" << at << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In particular, it seems that `std::ios_base::ate` does *not* move the initial output pointer to the end with the example seen above. Obviously this would result in the first write overwriting the beginning of the file (which is what caused my trouble).

It seems that either the implementation is incorrect or else [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) is incorrect (*"The output position starts at the end of the file."*) and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) is ambiguous (*"seek to the end of stream immediately after open"*: which stream?).

There is obviously an easy workaround: just use `stream.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end)`.

So my question is thus: is my code incorrect? Is the implementation incorrect? Are the reference sites incorrect? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open. Using `out` without `app` or `in` truncates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can see from the following chart in N4296 [filebuf.members]

[image: file io]

The combination `binary | out` will open the file in the `stdio` equivalent of `"wb"`, which will `truncate to zero length or create binary file for writing` (N1570 7.21.5.2).

As counterintuitive as it sounds for an `ofstream`, you will need to add the `in` flag if you don't want your file to be truncated, or `app` if you want to avoid truncation and seek to the end of the file on each write.

Bonus tip: Unlike `fstream`, `ifstream` and `ofstream` will automatically or `std::ios_base::in` and `std::ios_base::out` respectively with any flags you provide to the constructor or to `open`. You can also use the object itself to access the flags:

```
std::ofstream check("test", check.in | check.binary | check.ate);
```

The checks for `good` can also be shortened to `if (!initial)` etc.

Comment: Oh derp. That *totally* makes sense... use the input flag to not truncate when there's a specific flat for truncate. Total sense right there. It was the issue though. Thanks :)

Comment: Counterintuitive indeed.  I had to write a sample program using this information before I would believe it to be true. Odd that one would open a file with the equivalent of the read flag when the goal is to manually write to the end and other parts of the file.  I would have thought that opening an output stream with the in flag to be an invalid use of an output stream object.  However it works as described.